# Inconsistent Code Actions Light Bulb Issue on VS Code 1.83.1 Across VM Instances: Seeking Community Assistance

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

I'm facing a peculiar issue with Visual Studio Code version 1.83.1 where the light bulb for code actions is behaving inconsistently across different VM instances. Despite using the same project, some instances display the light bulb, while others do not. I've checked extensions, ensured consistent configurations, and reviewed documentation without finding a solution. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into resolving this, your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Tried:
I've attempted to resolve the inconsistent appearance of the code actions light bulb in Visual Studio Code (version 1.83.1) across various VM instances. Actions taken include verifying and installing consistent extensions, ensuring workspace configurations are the same, and reviewing documentation for possible solutions.

Expected:
I expected the code actions light bulb to consistently appear across all VM instances when working with the same project. This is based on maintaining uniform configurations and utilizing the same set of extensions.

Resulted:
Unfortunately, despite these efforts, the code actions light bulb continues to behave inconsistently. In some VM instances, it appears as expected, while in others, it fails to show up. Seeking community insights or solutions to understand and resolve this behavior.